# How can I automate downloads using IDM?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to automate downloading using selenium python which in turn carries the link to IDM. However, the thing is I can't get to download using IDM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thisis not good practice in selenium automation

Whilst it is possible to start a download by clicking a link with a browser under Selenium’s control, the API does not expose download progress, making it less than ideal for testing downloaded files. This is because downloading files is not considered an important aspect of emulating user interaction with the web platform. Instead, find the link using Selenium (and any required cookies) and pass it to a HTTP request library like libcurl.

Please refer seleniumhq site

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax to run IDM in Python. It will download to the default local path. Use an additional parameter '/p' to change the local path if needed.

```
from subprocess import run

idm_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\idman.exe"
url = "example url"
filename = "song.mp3"
run([idm_path, '/d', url, '/f', filename, '/n'])
```

source: [Start IDM download from command line.](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/command_line.html)